# Do I need proof of relationship with sponsor to the UK

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas

I’m applying for a visitors visa, my uncle is a UK citizen and he’s sponsoring, the thing is I don’t have pictures of us together because he travelled when I was little, and we don’t really chat on WhatsApp. Hope this won’t be a problem.

Comment: What is your nationality? Do you have enough money to make this travel if he does not sponsor?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UK visa refusal on V 4.2 a + c (and sometimes 'e')](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92121/uk-visa-refusal-on-v-4-2-a-c-and-sometimes-e) The answer includes a comprehensive section on sponsors. You need to prove a ‘genuine relationship’, which likely includes not just the family relationship but **why** the relation would want to sponsor your visit. Having little or no evidence of reasonable contact between the two of you could be a red flag